# R, TRUE/FALSE needed in FindCorrelation

Tags: r, r-caret

I've created a simple correlation matrix in R and I'm trying to use caret for feature selection so I can remove the highly correlated X attributes.

Here is my code:

```
highlyCorrelated <- findCorrelation(correlationMatrix, cutoff = 0.90, verbose = FALSE, names = TRUE, exact = ncol(correlationMatrix) < 100)
```

- highlyCorrelated is the name for the new object
- correlationMatrix is the name of my correlation matrix

I'm getting the following error regardless of how I enter the function into R. Even if I only use one parameter I still get this error:

```
Error in if (x[i, j] > cutoff) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: print the value of i and j after the error occurs and check the value of x[i,j].

Comment: neither i, nor j are objects and cannot be found when trying to print

Comment: does you rcorrelation matrix have missing values?

Comment: no it does not have missing values

Comment: @user20650 was correct - I had NA values in my matrix. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and @user20650 answer was correct.
I always do the same "preprocess" to ensure finCorrelation works:

```
nums <- sapply(data, is.numeric)
data.numeric <- data[ , nums]

data.without_na <- na.omit(data.numeric)
cor_matrix <- cor(data.without_na)

findCorrelation(cor_matrix, 0.7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case the issue was, Infinite values in my data, which `use='complete.obs'` doesn't account for in cor().

Solved it by preprocessing the data with

```
data <- apply(data, 2, function(y) {y[!is.finite(y)]=NA; y})
```